# In launch4j wrapper, my custom log4j2 appender can't be found

Tags: java, log4j2, launch4j

I have a project, which uses a custom log4j2 appender, which works fine when started normally via a java command line with the maven jar-with-dependencies assembly.

However, when I create an exe-wrapper with launch4j, the appender cannot be found. Error:

```
2016-10-05 07:24:25,796 main ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "InMemRotAppender"
2016-10-05 07:24:25,812 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "InMemRotAppender" for logger config "root"
```

What could be the problem?

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" packages="priv.mtj.jjpv">
    <Appenders>
        <InMemRotAppender name="InMemRotAppender">
        </InMemRotAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="InMemRotAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Appender (located in the same project and packed into the same jar):

```
package priv.mtj.jjpv;
....
@Plugin(name = "InMemRotAppender", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public class InMemRotAppender extends AbstractAppender {
    ...
}
```

Launch4j config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>console</headerType>  <!-- normally gui -->
  <jar>C:\workspace\jjpv\target\jjpv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\workspace\jjpv\deploy\jjpv.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>C:\workspace\jjpv\deploy\jpview.ico</icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>priv.mtj.jjpv.JJPv</mainClass>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJdk</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: Have you tried `SET Launch4j=debug-all` to see if there are any complaints from launch4j? The jar must be missing a piece of log4j2 that the command line launch is finding.

Comment: ye also could you check inside the wrapped jar , to check which dependencies it has included and if it included your config files

Comment: @Gene I just tried it, and there is no difference from the behavior I described earlier. (I presume, that you referred to SET as in environment variable.)

Comment: @AntJavaDev First reaction: huh, can you do this? Then, I opened the exe with 7zip (this actually works o_O'') but I cannot see anything that is missing. Especially, it contains the complete org.apache.logging.log4j dependency, the custom logger class, and the log4j.xml. Thus, unfortunately, this seems to be another dead end.

Comment: The SET is for Windows shell. If you're in bash, try export Launch4j=debug-all .  The launcher will write to launch4j.log .  But if everything really is packaged, then the only explanation is that launch4j is running java in a different environment than it's run by your command line. Environment = shell variables + command line options. Figure out what the differences are.  (I think the log will have the command line for starters.)